# Javascript: Why .map method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I'm working on this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/) in leetcode by using **.map** method, but somehow it returns undefined. Could anybody please explain why this happened? I read the doc, and it says that **.map** usually returns an array.

```
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        const num = nums[i];
        nums.slice(i+1).map((element) => {
            if (num + element === target){
                return [i, nums.indexOf(element, i+1)];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Because if `num + element` is not `=== target`, you never issue a `return` in the callback, so the callback implicitly returns `undefined`.

Comment: `twoSum` doesn't ever return anything either (the only `return` is returning from the `map` callback, not `twoSum`). Also, you should never use `map` if you're not using the array it produces (details in my blog post [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/)).

Answer (score 1):

Just to add , this is like a starter example where we can use two pointer pattern.

First setup to apply two pointer is to sort the array.

Then take two pointers
first one starting at 0 index
and second one starting at last index

Traverse the loop and check the target and increment and decrement the pointers accordingly

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {

  nums.sort((a,b) => a-b )
  
  var startingIndex = 0
  
  var lastIndex = nums.length-1;
  
   while(startingIndex<lastIndex){
     
     if(nums[startingIndex] + nums[lastIndex] === target){
       console.log(nums[startingIndex], nums[lastIndex])
       startingIndex++;
       lastIndex--;
     }
     
     if(nums[startingIndex] + nums[lastIndex] < target){
       startingIndex++;
     }
     
     if(nums[startingIndex] + nums[lastIndex] > target){
       lastIndex--;
     }
   }
  
  
};

console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 20, 13, 15], 33));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here to achieve the result efficiently

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
  const map = new Map();
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
    if (map.has(nums[i])) return [map.get(nums[i]), i];
    else map.set(target - nums[i], i);
  }
};

console.log(twoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9));
```